# Filter table of PHP data that contains some text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a database of jobs listed by their jobID, and what I've set up is a search box where you can enter the jobID number and it brings up the relevant details for that number. What I want to do is be able to enter the first few digits of the jobID and have it filter all of the jobID's that contain those digits.

Is this possible without JavaScript or a j query?

This is my code for the search box and for the table that's inputting the results, respectively..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function search () {
    var jobSearch = document.getElementById('jobSearch').value;
    window.location.href = ('search.php?jobID='+jobSearch);
}
</script>

<input id="jobSearch" placeholder="Search Job No.."><button onClick="search();">Search</button></input>
```

And the results table..

```
<table class="auto details" data-type="table" data-other="" data-filter="jobs.jobID=<?php echo $_GET['jobID']; ?>" data-columns="jobID,customerName,machineName,staffName,operation,notes,operationStatus,pallets"></table>
```

Comment: You want the results to automatically populate as you are typing them in? If you want to do this with strictly PHP, you can't. You will need to write a function in javascript to listen to an event, and as a key is pressed, you submit an ajax call to a separate PHP page that searches the database for that result. You can use the SQL syntax `LIKE '%{YOURSEARCH}'`

Comment: Hi @AdamJosephLooze, there's no need for it to populate as the keywords are entered. Just for the variable entered to be used in the next page. I've set up a search.php page that is opened when the search is submitted and it takes the entered keywords as the variable to filter the table with.

Comment: Then you should just create an HTML form `<form method="GET" action="search.php"><input type="text" name="jobID"><button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></form>` Copy and paste that into your page and give it a shot. If this is what you are looking for that is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dataTable](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin which will do the sorting ,searching for you.Just see the example in the following link

```
https://www.datatables.net/
```

You don't need to reconfigure so much.Just  download the dataTable plugin add the css and js to your php file and in your script just add following two lines

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable(); //replace the #example and put your table ID here
} );
```

hope that it will help.Thanks

Comment: As awesome as that table's functionality is, I think it's a bit too much and would require a lot of recoonfiguring my site to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an HTML form. I can see with your javascript that you want to pass the variable through the URL. This can be done using method GET in your form.

```
<form method="GET" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="jobID" placeholder="Enter Job ID">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, on your search page, you can use something like this,

Using PDO:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "jobs";
// Connect to DB
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $servername . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $username, $password);

// Process search
if(isset($_GET['jobID'])) {
    $jobID = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['jobID']))));
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobID LIKE '%$jobID%' LIMIT 100");
    $stmt->execute();
    $jobs = "";
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $jobs .= '<p>' . $row["jobID"] . '</p>';
    }
}
?>
<div class="jobs-list">
    <?php print $jobs; ?>
</div>
```

Or using mysqli:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "jobs";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_GET['jobID'])) {
    $jobID = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['jobID']))));
    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $jobs = "";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $jobs .= '<p>' . $row["jobID"] . '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $jobs = '<p>0 results</p>';
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
<div class="jobs-list">
    <?php print $jobs; ?>
</div>
```

For mysqli, `$conn` is the name of your db connection. For PDO, `$pdo` is the name of your db connection.

I recommend using the following to sanitize your variable before running through SQL.

`$jobID = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['jobID']))));`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you already have a script that is loading search page and prepends a variable jobID to the url.

Now on a search.php page you need to add

```html
if(isset($_GET['jobID'])) { // this checks if job id was set



//and place your code here to grad bata from the database and output
//below is just an example of getting data from the database:
$jobID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['jobID']);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "SELECT * from jobs WHERE job.id like '%{$jobID}%' ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['title'];
    }
    $result->free();
}


}
```